# Sequelize creates an unknown column after declaring assocations. The weird column has a name pattern of 'TableNameTableNameId'

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have a model declaration of such.

```
const Account = Sequelize.define("Account", {
   account_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
   }
}

const Student = Sequelize.define("Student", {
   student_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
   },

   account_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      unique: true,
      allowNull: false,
  }
}
```

Then I also have declared my associations like

```
Account.hasOne(models.Student);
Student.belongsTo(models.Account, {
   foreignKey: "account_id",
   allowNull: false,
});
```

The problem is that when I select the account and join or `include` the student, in its SQL statement it queries this column with a name of `AccountAccountId`.
This then raises an error that it cannot find that column.

This my query

```
const account = await Account.findOne({
      attributes: ["account_id", "is_active"],
      include: [
        {
          model: Student,
          attributes: ["student_id", "account_id"],
          where: {
            student_id: id,
          },
        },
      ],
    });
```

The error is
Unknown column 'Student.AccountAccountId' in 'on clause' (errno 1054) (sqlstate 42S22) (CallerID: 0kxatsabmiwg49ko77ez):

My package json dependencies:

```
{
"dependencies": {
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "csurf": "^1.11.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "https": "^1.0.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mysql2": "^2.3.3",
    "passport": "^0.6.0",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "sequelize": "^6.25.8"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a typical mistake while defining paired associations: if you indicate a custom `foreignKey` option with the name of a foreign key column in one association you should indicate the same foreign key name in the second association as well:

```
Account.hasOne(models.Student, { foreignKey: "account_id" });
Student.belongsTo(models.Account, {
   foreignKey: "account_id",
   allowNull: false,
});
```

By default Sequelize gives a name for a foreign key column as: ModelNameId (should be `AccountId` in this case).

Comment: Yes, that actually worked. I guess defining the foreignKey on both associations is necessary.