# i can't insert field into a table in Sequelize with foreign key

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

i can insert data into table except one field with foreign key(userId)

[cart table data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdjwt.png)

here is my cart model

```
const CartModel = db.define("cart", {
    status: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    totalPrice: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER
    }
}, {
    freezeTableName: true
})

CartModel.belongsTo(UserModel)
UserModel.hasMany(CartModel, {
    foreignKey: "userId",
    onDelete: "cascade",
    onUpdate: "cascade"
})
export default CartModel
```

here is my addToCart function

```
export const addToCart = async (req, res) => {
    const { userId} = req.body;

    try {

        const newCart = await CartModel.create({
            userId: userId,
            status: 'active'
        });

        res.status(200).json({
            msg: 'Item added to cart successfully',
            newCart
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error adding item to cart:', error);
        res.status(400).json({msg: 'Failed to add item to cart'});
    }
};
```

here is the route

```
router.post("/v1/addToCart/", addToCart)

export default router;
```

here is ho i post
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Eo1l.png)

i expected i can insert the field completely

Comment: Hi, using images for code or errors causes a lot of problems. Use images only to illustrate graphical issues. Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7353417).  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should indicate the same `foreignKey` option in both paired associations, see my [asnwer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74836051/1376618)

```js
CartModel.belongsTo(UserModel, {
    foreignKey: "userId" })
UserModel.hasMany(CartModel, {
    foreignKey: "userId",
    onDelete: "cascade",
    onUpdate: "cascade"
})
```