# Creating a new record on an associated Sequelize table needs first letter to be upper case

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm working on a project using NodeJS, Sequelize (6.35.2) and Postgres (8.11.3) and I'm getting this weird behavior. But first, here are the models...

**user.js**

```
const { Model, DataTypes } = require('sequelize')
const { sequelize } = require('../db')

class User extends Model {
  toJSON() {
    return { ...super.toJSON(), password: null, confirmationCode: null } 
  }
}

User.init({
  firstName: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
  lastName: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
  email: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
  password: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
  confirmationCode: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
  state: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    defaultValue: 'pending',
    allowNull: false
  }
}, {
  sequelize,
  underscored: false
})

module.exports = {
  User
}
```

**user_reset_token.js**

```
const { Model, DataTypes } = require('sequelize')
const { sequelize } = require('../db')
const { User } = require('./user')

class UserResetToken extends Model {

}

UserResetToken.init({
  token: {
    type: DataTypes.TEXT,
    allowNull: false
  },
  expiresIn: {
    type: DataTypes.DATE,
    allowNull: false
  },
  state: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    defaultValue: 'active',
    allowNull: false
  }
}, {
  sequelize,
  underscored: false
})

UserResetToken.belongsTo(User)

module.exports = {
  UserResetToken
}
```

And then, I need to create the **UserResetToken** record like this:

```
const createUserResetToken = async userId => {
  // I'm sure there are better ways of generating this token but, let's start with this for now.
  const token = uuidv4()
  const expiresIn = new Date()

  expiresIn.setMinutes(expiresIn.getMinutes() + 30)

  const userResetToken = await UserResetToken.create({
    UserId: userId,
    token,
    expiresIn,
    state: ACTIVE
  })

  return userResetToken.id ? token : false
}
```

Notice the **UserId** with the capital U. If I try doing **userId**, I get the record with a null value in the column.

I would love to do all of this just using camelCase, I also tried using underscored: true but the problem gets way worse.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to use non-default explicit foreign key field name then indicate it in `foreignKey` option in the associations:

```js
UserResetToken.belongsTo(User, { foreignKey: 'userId' })
```

Also see my other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74836051/1376618)